# Azure AD - Custom claim based on group memberships

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

I'm migrating from ADFS to Azure.

For each user, I need a list of all sectors he belongs to:

```
<Attribute Name="http://example.com/attributes/sector">
    <AttributeValue>aaa</AttributeValue>
    <AttributeValue>bbb</AttributeValue>
    <AttributeValue>ddd</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
```

I have an AD group for each sector:

- grp_aaa
- grp_bbb
- grp_ccc
- grp_ddd

To assign a user to a sector I just have to add him to the appropriate group.

In ADFS, I have one "Send Group Membership as a Claim" rule for each group, with an appropriate value. All these claims have the **same** custom outgoing claim type and that's how all values are grouped together as part of the same attribute.

But I can't figure out how to do the same in Azure.

With group claims, it is impossible to specify custom values. With normal claims, if I specify more than one rule in claim conditions, only the last value is being sent as part of the response. It is also impossible to specify more than one claim with the same name.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims? This shows how to emit group membership claims with several different options that may be of help to you.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no mention of how to emit custom values for each group. You can emit only group names, group SID, or something like that.

Comment: Gotcha - Now it makes more sense. I don’t know a direct way to do this.